# Read line once without removing it Python using .readline()

Tags: python, python-3.3

I would like to count the occurences of missings of every line in a txt file.

`foo.txt` file:

```
1 1 1 1 1 NA    # so, Missings: 1
1 1 1 NA 1 1    # so, Missings: 1
1 1 NA 1 1 NA   # so, Missings: 2
```

But I would also like to obtain the amount of elements for the first line (assuming this is equal for all lines).

```
miss = []
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        miss.append(line.count("NA"))

>>> miss
[1, 1, 2]         # correct
```

The problem is when I try to identify the amount of elements. I did this with the following code:

```
miss = []
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    elements = first_line.count(" ")  # given that values are separated by space
    for line in f:
        miss.append(line.count("NA"))

>>> (elements + 1)
6   # True, this is correct          
>>> miss 
[1,2]  # misses the first item due to readline() removing lines.`
```

How can I read the first line once without removing it for the further operation?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Just calculate the length for _each_ line inside the loop: `for line in f: ... elements = len(line.split())`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `f.seek(0)`. This will reset the file handle to the beginning of the file.

Complete example would then be:

```
miss = []
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    elements = first_line.count(" ")  # given that values are separated by space
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        miss.append(line.count("NA"))
```

Even better would be to read all lines, even the first line, only once, and checking for number of elements only once:

```
miss = []
elements = None
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if elements is None:
            elements = line.count(" ")  # given that values are separated by space
        miss.append(line.count("NA"))
```

BTW: wouldn't the number of elements be `line.count(" ") + 1`?

I'd recommend using `len(line.split())`, as this also handles tabs, double spaces, leading/trailing spaces etc.

Answer (score 2):

Provided all lines have the number of items you can just count items in the last line:

```
miss = []
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        miss.append(line.count("NA")
    elements = len(line.split())
```

A better way to count is probably:

```
elements = len(line.split())
```

because this also counts items separated with multiple spaces or tabs.

Comment: Note that `.count(" ")` will be off by 1, so `len(split)` is the only correct one.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. That is the way I would do it. In addition, often there are  more than one space or tabs in between items. Deleted the OP version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just treat the first line separately

```
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    first_line = next(f1)
    elements = first_line.count(" ")  # given that values are separated by space
    miss = [first_line.count("NA")]
    for line in f:
        miss.append(line.count("NA")
```

Comment: What exactly is next then?